# Optimal way to compute multiple numbers from their binary representation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, optimization, summation, algorithms, binary

Assume we are given an $n$-bit number $s=(s_0\dots s_{n-1})_2$ in binary representation and we want to evaluate the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}s_i2^i$. In the worst case, when all $s_i=1$, this becomes a sum of $n$ elements (assuming the $2^i$ are already known).

I am currently looking at ways to optimize this for multiple $n$-bit numbers by partially computing them at the same time. For example, if we have $N=2$ numbers, e.g. $s=(s_0\dots s_{n-1})_2$ and $r=(r_0\dots r_{n-1})_2$, then the worst case cost can also be reduced to a sum of $n$ elements (instead of $2n$) as follows. Let $R=\{i\mid r_i=1\}$ and $S=\{i\mid s_i=1\}$, then we can first  compute
$$ t=\sum_{i\in R\cap S}r_i2^i\,,\quad\text{ and then }\quad  s=t+\sum_{i\in S\backslash R}s_i2^i \quad\text{and}\quad r=t+\sum_{i\in R\backslash S}r_i2^i\,, $$
which gives a total of $\#(R\cap S)+\#(S\backslash R)+\#(R\backslash S)=\#(R\cup S)$ summands. In the worst case, $\#(R\cup S)=n$.

I've been trying to find a similar approach for higher $N$, but I am already struggling with the case $N=3$, especially since the sets (such as $S$ and $R$) don't add up as nicely as for $N=2$. I realized that the approach for $N=2$ can be easily extended to any even integer $N=2k$ by evaluating the numbers pairwise, thus at least giving an upper bound of $kn$ summands in these cases. Is there maybe a straightforward approach I don't see, or already something in the literature about these approaches? I guess there should be some kind of closed formula for given $n$ and $N$, but I can't seem to find it, maybe since I don't exactly know what to search for.

Thank you very much for any leads!

Comment: You may want to read up on base conversion algorithms. There are several of them beyond the sum of powers of $2$.

Comment: Note that if all elements are one you do not need to sum all elements - the result will be $2^{n}-1$

Comment: One way to speed up the process is to group the bits in contiguous chunks of fixed size $m$ and then look at the problem as converting a number from base $2^m$ to decimal.  For example, if you group in chunks of $8$ bits, you are effectively converting from hexadecimal to decimal.  You can pre-compute a table of decimal values of the chunks.